# jQuery code in an AngularJS directive

Tags: jquery, angularjs, google-maps, angularjs-directive, google-maps-markers

I want the following element to display Google Map:

```
<div id="map" class="gmaps" ></div>
```

For which I have the following js added:

```
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

And following script code is calling the `ContactUs.init()` method:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        ContactUs.init();
    });
</script>
```

The code for this is inside the `contact-us.js` file as follows:

```
var ContactUs = function () {
    return {
        //main function to initiate the module
        init: function () {
            var map;
            $(document).ready(function(){
              map = new GMaps({
                div: '#map',
                lat: 41.156863,
                lng: -81.855722
            });
            var marker = map.addMarker({
                lat: 41.156863,
                lng: -81.855722,
                title: 'Foo Inc.',
                infoWindow: {
                    content: "<b>Foo Inc.</b><br>123 Bar Ave, Fred 940<br>San Francisco, CA 94124"
                }
            });

               marker.infoWindow.open(map, marker);
            });
        }
    };
}();
```

How could I make the above code work using a AngularJS attribute directive in the `<div id="map" class="gmaps" ></div>` element?

**EDIT:**

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'Pool.<InfoWindowView>' of undefined
    at JT (eval at <anonymous> (eval at <anonymous> (eval at <anonymous> (http://maps.gstatic.com/cat_js/maps-api-v3/api/js/18/6/%7Bmain,geometry,places%7D.js:56:919))), <anonymous>:3:861)
    at KT (eval at <anonymous> (eval at <anonymous> (eval at <anonymous> (http://maps.gstatic.com/cat_js/maps-api-v3/api/js/18/6/%7Bmain,geometry,places%7D.js:56:919))), <anonymous>:4:31)
    at MT.(anonymous function).j (eval at <anonymous> (eval at <anonymous> (eval at <anonymous> (http://maps.gstatic.com/cat_js/maps-api-v3/api/js/18/6/%7Bmain,geometry,places%7D.js:56:919))), <anonymous>:6:951)
    at http://maps.gstatic.com/cat_js/maps-api-v3/api/js/18/6/%7Bmain,geometry,places%7D.js:37:1008
    at $f (http://maps.gstatic.com/cat_js/maps-api-v3/api/js/18/6/%7Bmain,geometry,places%7D.js:26:58)
    at Fh.map_changed (http://maps.gstatic.com/cat_js/maps-api-v3/api/js/18/6/%7Bmain,geometry,places%7D.js:37:978)
    at Ze (http://maps.gstatic.com/cat_js/maps-api-v3/api/js/18/6/%7Bmain,geometry,places%7D.js:19:190)
    at Fh.M.set (http://maps.gstatic.com/cat_js/maps-api-v3/api/js/18/6/%7Bmain,geometry,places%7D.js:18:853)
    at Fh.(anonymous function).open (http://maps.gstatic.com/cat_js/maps-api-v3/api/js/18/6/%7Bmain,geometry,places%7D.js:37:807)
    at link (http://localhost:3000/javascripts/app.js:219:31) <div id="map" class="gmaps margin-bottom-40" style="height: 400px; position: relative; overflow: hidden; -webkit-transform: translateZ(0px); background-color: rgb(229, 227, 223);">
```

**Code for the angular partial displaying Google Map:**

```
<div class="main">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row margin-bottom-40">
            <!-- BEGIN CONTENT -->
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="content-page">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <div id="map" class="gmaps margin-bottom-40" style="height:400px;"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 sidebar2">
                            <h3 class="support">Our Contact Info</h3>
                            <!-- Remaining stuff-->
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- END CONTENT -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can use this. https://github.com/allenhwkim/angularjs-google-maps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to create a directive:

gmaps.js implementation:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
});

app.directive('gmaps', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'C', // restrict this directive to css class with name gmaps
    link: function() {
      var map = new GMaps({
        div: '#map',
        lat: 41.156863,
        lng: -81.855722
      });

      var marker = map.addMarker({
        lat: 41.156863,
        lng: -81.855722,
        title: 'Foo Inc.',
        infoWindow: {
          content: "<b>Foo Inc.</b><br>123 Bar Ave, Fred 940<br>San Francisco, CA 94124"
        }
      });

      marker.infoWindow.open(map, marker);
    }
  };
});
```

html:

```
  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <div id="map" class="gmaps" style="width:500px; height: 500px"></div>
    <p>Hello {{name}}!</p>
  </body>
```

standard google api:

```
app.directive('gmaps', function($timeout) {
  return {
    restrict: 'C',
    link: function(scope) {

      var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(41.156863,-81.855722);

      var mapOptions = {
        center: myLatlng,
        zoom: 8
      };
      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);

      var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: "<b>Foo Inc.</b><br>123 Bar Ave, Fred 940<br>San Francisco, CA 94124"
      });

      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatlng,
        map: map
      });
      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
      });

      infowindow.open(map, marker);

    }
  };
});
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/z4HAIdGaYjNa2waOcrqE?p=preview

Comment: It works just fine the first I naviaget to the partial that has the `<div id="map" class="gmaps" style="width:500px; height: 500px"></div>` code, but when I come to it the second time it gives me the following error:`TypeError: Cannot read property 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'Pool.<InfoWindowView>' of undefined`. Complete error I've added in the edit of the question.

Comment: @skip could you post the complete html of your page?  Also what do you mean by "I navigated to the partial"? do you mean ng-view?

Comment: The information Window on which it shows the address does not display. The marker displays alright. Sorry about the earlier comment.

Comment: I've edited the post and added the code for partial as well on which Google Map with the `div` element responsible for displaying marker and information window.

Comment: Yes, MajoB, I meant the angular partial taking the place at `ng-view`.

Comment: The second time I access the partial (`ng-view`) that displays Google Map code, I do not get the `infoWindow` with `Foo Inc. 123 Bar Ave, Fred 940 San Francisco, CA 94124` information at the marker.

Comment: @skip seems like problem with gmaps.js could you use plain gooogle api?

Comment: @skip the problem is the marker.infoWindow.open(map, marker); if you remove it then the error disappears

Comment: Thanks MajoB, but I am still getting the same error. And this might be really stupid but I am not sure I understand what it means by plain Google API? Could you please tell me which API to use to do away with this issue. The error is persistent wven when I comment out the `marker.infoWindow.open(map, marker);` line.

Comment: I think may be `marker.infoWindow.open(map, marker);` is being called just the first time the angular partial (`ui-view`) is being accessed. May be thats why the infoWindow is not popping up at the marker when its been accessed the second time.

Comment: @skip i created a new example with plain google maps api http://plnkr.co/edit/Kwb78R2gT7XTe1dLWNRJ?p=preview seems it is working now. this is the standard google api https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial and this what have you been used http://hpneo.github.io/gmaps/

Comment: You have absolutely nailed this. Thanks a ton :)